# Create different objects based on multiple parameters

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a REST API. I need to create presentation (DTO) object, but the construction of this object depends on request - it differs in 15%. 
I wonder what pattern should I use.

My case:

```
//presentation-DTO
class Item {
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $tags;
    private $liked; //is Liked by logged user
    ...

    public function __construct(Item $item, bool $liked, ...)
    {
        $this->name = $item->getName();
        $this->price = $item->getPrice();
        $this->tags = $item->getTags();
        $this->liked = $liked;
        ...
    }
}
```

When user is not logged in - I don't need $liked

When showing list of items - I don't need $tags

And there are more attributes that works as above.

My first idea was to use Builder principle.

```
$itemBuilder = new ItemBuilder();
$itemBuilder->setItem($item);
...
if($user) {
    $itemBuilder->setUserLiked($userLiked);
    ...
}
return $itemBuilder->build();
```

It solves my problem with too many parameters in constructor.

But still, I also don't need all parameters to be constructed - eg. I don't need tags (on lists). As I use lazy load, I don't want my dto constructor to call them.

So I thought, maybe Factory.. but then my problem with too many (and optional) parameters is returning.

How will you solve this?

Comment: **When user is not logged in** [1] you don't want to pass `$liked` as parameter to constructor?  **OR**  [2] Its okay to pass `$liked` as parameter to constructor but you do not want to call `$this->liked = $item->getLiked();` since `When user is not logged in - I don't need $liked`. Explain bit more.

Comment: There are two cases. [a] Information about $liked, comes from separated data. I can't get them from $item object - need to pass them as parameter. [b] Information about $tokes comes from $item object, but I don't want them to be called in constructor, when I don't need them. So in case [a], I don't want to pass them [1]. In case [b] - I don't want to call them. In bot cases, I don't want to have this attributes in dto object - if I don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have required points to make a comment hence an answer.

What are you trying to do with the `Item` class. Your class is `Item` and first parameter is also of type `Item`. I cannot visualizes how its going to work.

I will prefer to keep business login to set proper properties in a separate class:

```
/**
 * A class for business logic to set the proper properties
 */
class ItemProperties {
    private $item;
    public $isLogin    = false;
    public $showList   = false;
    .....

    public function __construct(Item &$item) {
        //  set all properties;
    }


    public function getProperties() {
        $retVal     = [];
        if($this->isLogin == true) {
            $retVal['liked']    = true;
        }

        if($this->showList == true) {
            $retVal['tags'] = $this->item->getTags();
        }

        if(....) {
            $retVal['...']  = $this->item->.....();
        }

        return $retVal;
    }
}

/**
 * DTO
 */
class Item {
    public function __construct(ItemProperties $itemProps) {
        $this->setItemProps($itemProps);
    }

    // If you prefer lazy loading here...maybe make it public
    // and remove call from constructor.
    private function setItemProps(&$itemProps) {
        $properties = $itemProps->getProperties();
        foreach($properties AS $propName => $propValue) {
            $this->$propName    = $propValue;
        }
    }
}


// Usage:
$itemProps = new ItemProperties($Item);
//  set other properties if you need to...
$itemProps->isLogin = false;

$item   = new Item($itemProps);
```

Comment: You understood it well. Item class is DTO, and it gets item property, that is ORM entity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gave me a fresh look. There is just one think that need to be reconsidered. In your solution, ItemProperties class works like a builder (stores info needed to create object) and also, it stores information about what properties will DTO object has - so it has more than one responsibility.  I think, that ItemProperties class should only stores data and validate if proper types are set... and there should be different class that determines what properties will DTO has. Also, getProperties method will be hard to keep simple and develope it.